# Mulit Stepper Form Formik and Yup Validation

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I need assistance in optimizing the implementation of Formik and Yup validation in a React JS project. Currently, I have implemented it, but I am facing an issue. When I click on the `production_number` field in the first wizard and do not enter any input, it does not show an error until I click the save button in the last step. The current implementation consists of a single form, `DisruptionEventCreateForm`, which includes the `Wizard1`, `Wizard2`, and `Wizard3` components as children. These components receive formik as a prop and utilize it within their respective components.

I would like to enhance the implementation so that the error is displayed immediately when the `production_number` field loses focus, rather than waiting until the save button is clicked. Please provide guidance on how to achieve this.

Thank you for your assistance.

**DisruptionEventCreateForm Code**

```
const DisruptionEventCreateForm = () => {
  const i18n = useI18n();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(0);
  const [completed, setCompleted] = useState<{ [k: number]: boolean }>({});

  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    production_number: Yup.string()
      .required('Production number is required')
      .matches(/^[0-9-]+$/, 'Only numeric values with hyphens are allowed'),
    location: Yup.string().required('Location is required'),
    fault_category: Yup.string().required("Fault Category Required!"),
    fault: Yup.string().required("Fault is Required")
  });

  const totalSteps = () => {
    return steps.length;
  };

  const completedSteps = () => {
    return Object.keys(completed).length;
  };

  const isLastStep = () => {
    return activeStep === totalSteps() - 1;
  };

  const allStepsCompleted = () => {
    return completedSteps() === totalSteps();
  };

  const handleNext = () => {
    const newActiveStep =
      isLastStep() && !allStepsCompleted()
        ? // It's the last step, but not all steps have been completed,
          // find the first step that has been completed
        steps.findIndex((step, i) => !(i in completed))
        : activeStep + 1;
    setActiveStep(newActiveStep);
  };


  const handleBack = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep - 1);
  };

  const handleStep = (step: number) => () => {
    setActiveStep(step);
  };

  const handleComplete = () => {
    const newCompleted = completed;
    newCompleted[activeStep] = true;
    setCompleted(newCompleted);
    handleNext();
  };

  const handleReset = () => {
    setActiveStep(0);
    setCompleted({});
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const options = {
      inactive: true,
      sort: 'name',
    };

    const getLines = () => {
      lineService.getLines(options).then((results) => {
        setLines(results.data);
      });
    };

    getLines();
    //TODO getMaterials
  }, []);

  const submitSubFunction = (disruptionEvent: DisruptionEventDto) => {
    disruptionEventService
      .createDisruptionEvent(disruptionEvent)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('created successfully');
        navigate('/');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.message.includes('NotNull')){
          setErrorDialogOpen(true);
          setErrorMessage(i18n.translate('Could not create a disruption due to missing information, please fill in all required data'));
          setErrorTitle(i18n.translate('Error creating Disruption!'))
        }
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  const handleCancel = () => {
    navigate('/');
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: '60%', display: 'block', justifyContent: 'center', marginRight: 'auto', marginLeft: 'auto' }}>
      <Box sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
        <Stepper nonLinear activeStep={activeStep}>
          {steps.map((label, index) => (
            <Step key={label} completed={completed[index]}>
              <StepButton color={'inherit'} onClick={handleStep(index)}>
                {label}
              </StepButton>
            </Step>
          ))}
        </Stepper>
        <Box display={'flex'} justifyContent={'space-between'}>
          <Button disabled={activeStep === 0} onClick={handleBack}>
            <ArrowBackIosIcon />
          </Button>
          <Typography sx={{ mt: 2, mb: 1, py: 1 }}>{steps[activeStep]}</Typography>
          <Button onClick={handleNext}>
            <ArrowForwardIosIcon style={{ marginRight: '1px' }} />
          </Button>
        </Box>
        <div>
          <Formik initialValues={defaultDisruptionEvent}
                  validationSchema={validationSchema}
                  onSubmit={submitSubFunction}>
            {(formik) =>
              <Form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit} autoComplete="off">
                {activeStep === 0 && (
                  <WizardStep1
                    formik={formik}
                    disruptionEvent={formik.values}
                    locations={locations}
                  />
                )}
                {activeStep === 1 && (
                  <WizardStep2
                    disruptionEvent={formik.values}
                    handleChange={formik.handleChange}
                    faultRecipients={faultRecipients}
                  />
                )}
                {activeStep === 2 && (
                  <WizardStep3
                    disruptionEvent={formik.values}
                    handleChange={formik.handleChange}
                  />
                )}
                {activeStep === steps.length - 1 && <Box component="div" sx={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
                  <Controls.Button color="secondary" onClick={handleCancel} variant="contained">
                    {i18n.translate('Cancel')}
                  </Controls.Button>
                  <Controls.Button color="primary" type="submit" variant="contained">
                    {i18n.translate('Save')}
                  </Controls.Button>
                </Box>}
              </Form>
            }
          </Formik>
        </div>
        {allStepsCompleted() ? (
          <React.Fragment>
            <Typography sx={{ mt: 2, mb: 1 }}>All steps completed - you&apos;re finished</Typography>
            <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', pt: 2 }}>
              <Box sx={{ flex: '1 1 auto' }} />
              <Button onClick={handleReset}>Reset</Button>
            </Box>
          </React.Fragment>
        ) : (
          <React.Fragment>
            <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', pt: 2 }}>
              {activeStep !== steps.length &&
                (completed[activeStep] ? (
                  <Typography variant="caption" sx={{ display: 'inline-block' }}>
                    Step {activeStep + 1} already completed
                  </Typography>
                ) : (
                  <Button onClick={handleComplete}>
                    {completedSteps() === totalSteps() - 1 ? 'Finish' : 'Complete Step'}
                  </Button>
                ))}
            </Box>
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default DisruptionEventCreateForm;


**WizardStep1**

const momentFormatString = 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm';

interface Props {
  disruptionEvent: Dtos.DisruptionEventDto;
  lines: Dtos.LineDto[];
  materials: Dtos.MaterialDto[];
  formik: FormikProps<DisruptionEventDto>;
}

const WizardStep1 = ({
                       formik,
                       disruptionEvent,
                       lines,
                       materials,
                     }: Props) => {

  // to set names to null in main object when you unselect a parent dropdown
  const handleUnsetChildren = (keys: string[], formik: FormikProps<FormikValues>): any => {
    keys.forEach((key) =>
      formik.handleChange({
        target: {
          name: key,
          value: null,
        },
      }),
    );
    return null;
  };

  const handleMaterialSwitchChange = (event: any, formik: FormikProps<FormikValues>) => {
    formik.handleChange({
      target: {
        name: 'with_custom_material',
        value: event.target.checked,
      },
    });

    formik.handleChange({
      target: {
        name: 'material',
        value: null,
      },
    });
  };

  return (
    <Box>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <FormSectionHeader heading="Location and Time" caption="When and where does the disturbance occur?" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <Controls.Select
            name="line"
            label="Line"
            value={disruptionEvent && disruptionEvent.line ? disruptionEvent.line.uuid : ''}
            items={lines
              .filter((line) => (disruptionEvent.location ? isMatch(line.location, disruptionEvent.location) : false))
              .map((e) => ({ id: e.uuid, value: e.name }))}
            onChange={(event) =>
              formik.handleChange({
                target: {
                  name: 'line',
                  value:
                    event.target.value.toString() !== ''
                      ? getSelectedItem(event.target.value.toString(), lines)
                      : handleUnsetChildren(['station'], formik),
                },
              })
            }
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <FormSectionHeader
            heading="Material and Product"
            caption="Please enter the affected material model and product"
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <Controls.Select
            name="material"
            label="Material"
            disabled={disruptionEvent.with_custom_material}
            value={
              disruptionEvent && disruptionEvent.material && disruptionEvent.material.uuid
                ? disruptionEvent.material.uuid
                : ''
            }
            items={materials.map((e) => ({ id: e.uuid, value: `${e.material_number} - ${e.name}` }))}
            onChange={(event) =>
              formik.handleChange({
                target: {
                  name: 'material',
                  value:
                    event.target.value.toString() !== ''
                      ? getSelectedItem(event.target.value.toString(), materials)
                      : null,
                },
              })
            }
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <FormLabel>Enter Material Manually?</FormLabel>
          <Controls.ScSwitch
            name="with_custom_material"
            label="Allow?"
            checked={disruptionEvent ? disruptionEvent.with_custom_material : false}
            onChange={(event) => handleMaterialSwitchChange(event, formik)}
          />
        </Grid>
        {disruptionEvent &&
          !disruptionEvent.with_custom_material &&
          disruptionEvent.material &&
          disruptionEvent.material.uuid !== '' && (
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <Controls.TextField
                aria-readonly
                disabled
                value={disruptionEvent && disruptionEvent.material ? disruptionEvent.material.name : ''}
                variant="outlined"
                fullWidth
              />
            </Grid>
          )}
        {disruptionEvent && disruptionEvent.with_custom_material && (
          <>
            <Grid item xs={6}>
              <Controls.TextField
                name="material_number"
                label="Material number"
                value={(disruptionEvent && disruptionEvent.material && disruptionEvent.material.material_number) || ''}
                onChange={(event) =>
                  formik.handleChange({
                    target: {
                      name: 'material',
                      value: { ...disruptionEvent.material, material_number: event.target.value },
                    },
                  })
                }
                fullWidth
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6}>
              <Controls.TextField
                name="name"
                label="Material name"
                value={(disruptionEvent && disruptionEvent.material && disruptionEvent.material.name) || ''}
                onChange={(event) =>
                  formik.handleChange({
                    target: {
                      name: 'material',
                      value: { ...disruptionEvent.material, name: event.target.value },
                    },
                  })
                }
                fullWidth
              />
            </Grid>
          </>
        )}
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <Controls.TextField
            name="production_number"
            label="Production number"
            onChange={formik.handleChange}
            value={formik.values.production_number}
            error={formik.touched.production_number && Boolean(formik.errors.production_number)}
            helperText={formik.touched.production_number && formik.errors.production_number}
            fullWidth
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default WizardStep1;
```

Comment: There are formik props for validating on blur and on change.  You might want to set the onBlur to be true.
 `validateOnBlur: true,` `validateOnChange: false,`

All formik wrapper props are mentioned in the docs here <https://formik.org/docs/api/formik>